# Procedure does not paste value in the destination sheet

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010, paste

Ok i wrote this `small sub`:

```
Sub dingo()

Dim apriori
    Dim e As Integer
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim rr As Integer
    Dim yolk As Integer
    Dim timy As Integer

    'timy = yeah.Count

    rr = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Count
    yolk = rr
    e = 1

    For Each apriori In yeah


    'WE NEED LOOP ON THE COPYING MECHANISM!!!-re-test

    Dim Rng As Range

    If Trim(apriori) <> "" Then
        With Sheets(yolk).Range("1:1")
            Set Rng = .Find(apriori, .Cells(.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole, xlByRows, _
                            xlNext, False)
            yolk = yolk - 1
            'e = 1
            If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
                Application.Goto Rng, True
                ActiveCell.Offset(26, 0).Copy Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B2").Offset(, e).Paste
                e = e + 1

            Else
                MsgBox "Nothing found"
            End If
        End With
    End If


    Next apriori


End Sub
```

It is supposed to find a value and put it to a variable named `apriori` and then `Offset` 26 rows down.

However for a reason i do not know the macro does **not** paste the result in the destination sheet.... Any ideas why is this happening?

Comment: I am trying to test it again and again but it is part of a 9 min `macro` and this creates a terrible headache~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ActiveCell.Offset(26, 0).Copy Worksheets("EXTRACTIONS").Range("B2").Offset(, e).Paste
```

You don't need `.Paste` at the end of this line, you are supplying the Destination to which it will paste.

Comment: Thanks the macro was big and i just couldn't see it!

Comment: also you might not need the Goto (like select) and just replace with `rng.Offset(26, 0).`...